# Deploying a Contract vs. Instantiating a Contract

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, react

I apologize for the very basic question but I am a little confused. What is the difference between deploying a contract and instantiating a contract?

---

Answer (score 1):

**After the contract is deployed ,you can create an instance of that contract ,
to call his ,function or variables . :)

So we create instances of that contract to interact with it.**

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to create new contracts: deployment and instantiation.

When you deploy a contract it's done by sending a transaction to the blockchain. The transaction includes contract's bytecode and the transaction is used to create a new contract.

The other way to create contracts is for an existing contract to create a new contract. So something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 

contract A {

}

contract B {
    function create() public {
        A newContract = new A();
    }
}
```

Here the `newContract` will be a new instance of contract `A` in a new address. The `newContract` variable basically just contains the contract `A`'s address.

Comment: Does interacting with `contract B` in effect interact with the original contract, `contract A`?

Comment: Yes, the interaction is you -> B -> A (if you call some A's function from B). Contract A sees contract B as `msg.sender`.

Answer (score 0):

**Deploying a contract** means that it doesn't exist yet on the Blockchain.
You have the code, that you will compile and deploy on a Blockchain to be accessible. Once deployed it can be interacted with

**Instantiating a contract** is defining a an object of a *new contract* **OR** an *already existing/deployed* contract, so that you can interact with it within a contract:

```
    ERC20 public erc20Instance1 = ERC20([address_of_the_already_deployed_contract])

    ERC20 public erc20Instance2 = new ERC20()

    function interactWithInstance1(uint amount,address from, address to) public {
      erc20Instance1.transferFrom(from, to, amount);
    }

   function interactWithInstance2(uint amount,address from, address to) public {
      erc20Instance2.transferFrom(from, to, amount);
    }
```